# Image captured from custom camera gets rotated after cropping iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-image, ciimage

I am facing issue of image rotation after cropping image. I have placed step by step methods below which i have used currently.

**Here is the process i followed to get result :**

**Step:1**
Take photo through custom camera

```
- (void)captureImageWithCompletionHander:(void (^)(id))completionHandler{
    [_cameraOverlayView hideHightLightOverlay];
    if (_isCapturing) return;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf hideGLKView:YES completion:^{
        [weakSelf hideGLKView:NO completion:^{
            [weakSelf hideGLKView:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    }];
    _isCapturing = YES;

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections){
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ){
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) break;
    }

    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error){
        if(!CMSampleBufferIsValid(imageSampleBuffer)){
            return;
        }
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

        UIImage * capturedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData scale:1];
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 1.0).length);
        if (_myDevice == [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0]) {
            capturedImage = capturedImage;
        }else if (_myDevice == [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][1]) {
        }

        [weakSelf hideGLKView:NO completion:nil];
        completionHandler(capturedImage);
         _isCapturing = NO;
     }];
}
```

**Step:2** Fix orientation

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*) image{
    self =  [super init];
    if (self){
        self.originalImage = [image fixOrientation];
    }

    return self;
}

//Method for fix orientation
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
@end
```

**Step:3** Crop image

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image{
    CGFloat overlayHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = image.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = image.scale;
    CIImage *rawImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

    NSMutableDictionary *rectangleCoordinates = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputTopLeft"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(topLeftPath.x * _absoluteWidth, (overlayHeight - topLeftPath.y) * _absoluteHeight)];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputTopRight"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(topRightPath.x * _absoluteWidth, (overlayHeight - topRightPath.y) * _absoluteHeight)];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputBottomLeft"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(bottomLeftPath.x * _absoluteWidth, (overlayHeight - bottomLeftPath.y) * _absoluteHeight)];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputBottomRight"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(bottomRightPath.x * _absoluteWidth, (overlayHeight - bottomRightPath.y) * _absoluteHeight)];
    rawImage = [rawImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIPerspectiveCorrection" withInputParameters:rectangleCoordinates];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:rawImage fromRect:[rawImage extent]];
    UIImage *RImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];
    return RImage;
}
```

**Result:**

- After capturing image i am showing original image & it looks straight. No issues.

See image :
[image]

- But after cropping it gets rotated

See image :
[image]

**Some references which i already tried but not worked:**

[Using CoreImage to filter an image results in image rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075595/using-coreimage-to-filter-an-image-results-in-image-rotation/8229730#8229730)

[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)

[iOS - UIImageView - how to handle UIImage image orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915630/ios-uiimageview-how-to-handle-uiimage-image-orientation)

[How to get the Correct orientation of the image selected from the Default Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image)

[Convert a UIImage to a CIImage to crop to a CGRect. AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357010/convert-a-uiimage-to-a-ciimage-to-crop-to-a-cgrect-avfoundation)

It will be great if someone guide to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this for croping .. - (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*self.scale, 
                      rect.origin.y*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.width*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.height*self.scale);       

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                          scale:self.scale 
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

Comment: i think you should refer this answer for croping image i use this answer in my project and solve my prorblem  .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload Follow above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so many experiments & trying so many solutions, Finally i resolved it by moving to `UIBeizerPath`.

I noticed that the orientation issue was coming only because of `CIImage`, which never get resolved. Even a original image was getting correctly it was getting rotated after cropping just because of `CIImage`.

So tried with `UIBeizerPath` & here is the what i did :

```
UIBezierPath *path = [_overlayView getPath];
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
rect.size = _detectedImage.frame.size;

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _detectedImage.frame.size.width, _detectedImage.frame.size.height);
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[_detectedImage.layer setMask:shapeLayer];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_detectedImage.layer.frame.size, NO, 0);
[_detectedImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImage *cpImage = [outputImage imageByTrimmingTransparentPixelsRequiringFullOpacity:YES];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace orientation to UIImageOrientationUp in following line in your 'cropImage' method.

```
UIImage *RImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:originalScale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```